# RecyclerView OnClick pass through intent Long click adds marker to map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

Initially, I had a listview do the job for me, I would set the clicklistener and long licklistener as follows in the onCreate Main class:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserFeed.class);
            i.putExtra("venueName", businessList.get(position).name);
            i.putExtra("companyId",businessList.get(position).id);
            i.putExtra("canWrite", checkedIn);
            i.putExtra("Lat",businessList.get(position).anchorpt.getLatitude());
            i.putExtra("Lon",businessList.get(position).anchorpt.getLongitude());
            i.putExtra("NotType",venueType);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Double Lat = businessList.get(position).anchorpt.getLatitude();
            Double Lon = businessList.get(position).anchorpt.getLongitude();
            ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            mMap.clear();
            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude()))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker())
                    .title("My Location")
                    .visible(false)));
            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                    .visible(true)));

            for (Marker marker : markers){
                builder.include(marker.getPosition());
            }
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            int padding = 100;
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,padding);
            mMap.animateCamera(cu);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to do the same approach with the recyclerview, with no success. I can do it in the recylcerviewadapter but I'm not sure how I would add a marker. It would look like this:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{
    public TextView tvName,tvDistance,tvAgeRange,tvUserCount,tvGenderRatio,tvTimeDetails;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        //itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.venueName);
        tvDistance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDistance);
        tvAgeRange = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAgeRange);
        tvUserCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textUserCount);
        tvGenderRatio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textGenderRatio);
        tvTimeDetails = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.whenLitOccurs);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //context.startActivity(new Intent(context, UserFeed.class));
        int row = getAdapterPosition();
        Log.i("AppInfo","Item clicked"+ items.get(row));
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UserFeed.class);
        i.putExtra("venueName", items.get(row).name);
        i.putExtra("companyId",items.get(row).id);
        //i.putExtra("canWrite", checkedIn);
        i.putExtra("Lat",items.get(row).anchorpt.getLatitude());
        i.putExtra("Lon",items.get(row).anchorpt.getLongitude());
        //i.putExtra("NotType",venueType);
        context.startActivity(i);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        //Add a marker to map
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm using google maps v2.

Comment: whats the problem with implementing `onLongClick` then?

Comment: Sorry, I may have worded it poorly, but. What I am trying to do is add the onclick & onlonglcick listener for the recyclerview in "almost" the same fashion as I would with a regular listview; via the onCreate method in the main class and not in the adapter viewholder subclass. When I do, it doesn't detect the click

Comment: you are calling `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);` so it will work

Comment: It does work, perfectly but the problem is that I can't pass the venueType since it is in the onCreate activity in another class. I also can't add a marker to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont perform any  intense operation inside adapter , instead use callback methods (ex : interface) to transfer the click and longclick events to mainactivity

Step 1 : create an interface for clickListener.

```
public interface CustomAdapterClickListener {
public void onItemClick(View v, int position);}
```

Step 2 : Assign MainActivity reffrence to interface with the help of constructor of recylcerview.

```
public class RecylcerAdapter  extends extends RecyclerView.Adapter<>{
public RecylcerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<> list,
                       final CustomAdapterClickListener clickListener) {

    this.context = context;
    inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list = list;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}
```

}Step 3 : Call this interface method from onClicks method of adapter

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    clickListener.onItemClick(v,(int)v.getTag());
}
```

Step 4 : Implement the interface in MainActivity

```
public class MaiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomAdapterClickListener{

@Override
public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
    // now you have the list item position as well as view , get the adapter data based on the postion
    // add marker with the help of googlemap instance .()
}
```

}

Comment: What would that look like? How can I apply that to the map?

Comment: I can apply this to a long click as well?

Comment: Also, with what listener do you pass through when creating the adapter?

Comment: For example, do I use `new VenueDetailRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), businessList, this);` ? in the main activity on create?

Comment: yes for longClick also but u need to create one more interface for longclick.